# What should be saved (in SQL Server database) if it is no data (is null)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have SQL Server database entry `LastCheck` of datatype `DateTime`.

By first save it is no value, so it is `NULL`. `LastCheck` is configured to allow nulls.

What should I insert in my statement? How to initialise `LastCheck` in code? Should I convert `DateTime` to `null`?? I can't do just `LastCheck = null`, because it is from `DateTime` value.

```
Job job = new Job();
job.LastCheck = null;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Jobs (LastCheck)"
                  + " VALUES (@LastCheck)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastCheck", job.LastCheck));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should insert a null using `DbNull.Value`:

```
cmd.Parameters
   .Add(new SqlParameter("@LastCheck", job.LastCheck ?? DbNull.Value));
```

Comment: but my lastcheck is from type DateTime.. do i need to convert it?

Comment: @Ragims: if the column in SQL Server allows null, you can pass in `DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull.Value` is your correct answer - and I would additionally recommend specifying its type!

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastCheck", SqlDbType.DateTime));
cmd.Parameters["@LastCheck"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```